# Doctrine CouchDB ODM: How to retrieve Document when you don't know it's type

Tags: doctrine, couchdb

So i don't know the type of an document I want retrieve and thus have no idea how to retrieve this document in a doctrine manner.
Normally i would do somethink like that:

```
$dm->find('User', 12345);
```

And i should get the User class. 
But what if I don't know the type of the document? It's stored in document so Doctrine should figure it out. I **should** simple call

```
$dm->find(12345); //of course this doesn't work
```

and Doctrine **should** look into "type" field in the document and return the User class.

Of course i can do it by hand but maybe there is an Doctrine method for this problem?

So my question is: How to retrieve (using doctrine) the document and instantiate correct class (depending on the "type" field found in the document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think normally you would want to develop a [view](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) for each logical type of data that you want to look at, wherever it is in the document graph.

Otherwise you could write a view that looks at every document, looping through every property recursively, and find the value `12345`, but that of course would, probably, be very slow.

The views can look at your `type` property (which is [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)) and `emit()` the correct object.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but i think that getting documents by _id does not involve looping through all the documents? I think that "by id" view is already in store and calling http://couch.../db_name/12345 will retrieve me the document with id: 12345 very quickly because it's hashed.

Comment: They won't need to be iterated every time. The results of a view are incrementally stored in a B-tree structure for faster retrieval, but the first time, they must be iterated. Note that in my answer I did say 'looping through every property', by which I mean properties of each of the documents operated on in the view, because you were looking for a specific value in a child property.